# Azure devops REST API | Build Number extract to txt file

Tags: azure, powershell, api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to extract a build number via POWERSHELL to a TXT FILE, I have the GET request and the URI is arranged.

I have a format with PAT TOKEN, but I can't do it, how do I do OutFile to a TXT file?

```
# Build Auth header
$MyPat = "XXXX"
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$h = @{'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat}

$BuildNumberInfo = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$($Company)/$($Project)/_apis/build/builds/$($BuildID)?api-version=6.0-preview.6" -Method 'GET'
```

Comment: you do get a result? what is in the variable $BuildNumberInfo?

Comment: I got result from uri and method 'GET'
alot of content and in the content have : ,"id":13807,"buildNumber":"20220901.3","status":"completed","result":"succeeded"

Comment: so $BuildNumberInfo.buildNumber should give you what you want?

Comment: my target is to extract only the build number to txt file

Answer (score 0):

Use `Invoke-RestMethod` instead of `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
# Build Auth header
$MyPat = "XXX"
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$h = @{'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat}

$BuildNumberInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$($Company)/$($Project)/_apis/build/builds/$($BuildID)?api-version=6.0-preview.6" -Method 'GET' -Headers $h

$BuildNumberInfo.buildNumber | Out-File buildnumber.txt
```

Comment: Toda Raba
I will check it out tomorrow :)